# Mysql column sorting of string data with characters like `() ' "`

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have a table and it consists varchar data. The data present inside that column is like this.

```
"bcd"
cde
abcd
'xxx'
(zzz)
```

Now I want to sort according to alphabetical order. I have tried this query

```
select my_col from tbl_user order by ltrim(REPLACE(my_col,'"', '')) ASC
```

Its' output is as follows :

```
'xxx'
(zzz)
abcd
"bcd"
cde
```

But my desired output is, means while sorting it has to sort according to alphabetical order whether `"` present or not.

```
abcd
"bcd"
cde
'xxx'
(zzz)
```

How can I achieve this??. any ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try multiple `REPLACE`

```
ORDER BY REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(my_col,'"', ''), '(',''), ')', ''), '''','') ASC
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d042f8/2)

Comment: yes its working properly. thanks. I found nothing about replace function on net, can you give me its link.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar [here's the link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT id
FROM   tblNum
ORDER  BY REPLACE(id, SUBSTRING(id, PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z]%', id), 1), '')
```

Comment: PATINDEX is SQL Server-specific.

Comment: yeah I did not check the mysql tag its my mistake